# Kubuntu 22.04 plasma freeze, but mouse is mooving. Intel and nVidia Video Card problem?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 22.04, plasma, i915

I'm facing a very disturbing problem: randomically, 3 or 4/day, plasma freezes.
I can still move the mouse, and unplugging and plugging the HDMI cable I can defreeze it.
The problems seems to be realted to conflict between the nvidia and intel cards.

> Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel

> Device-2: NVIDIA GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 515.48.07

I've followed some instruction that suggest me to edit GRUB

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_dc=0 intel_idle.max_cstate=2"

The last command is to solve a flickering problem, but it seems not related at all with freeze.
I've noticed that the freeze may happen more often when I use a virtual machine ( virtual box ), the one that I use now for my job.
But not always, and it could be just a personal wrong consideration.

Here some information useful for solving the problem

nVidia Driver :

> NVIDIA-SMI 515.48.07    Driver Version: 515.48.07    CUDA Version: 11.7

Configurartion :

```
System:
  Host: Bestione Kernel: 5.15.0-43-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.24.6 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: Katana GF76 12UC v: REV:1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-17L4 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: E17L4IMS.108 date: 01/07/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 50.3 Wh (98.1%) condition: 51.3/52.0 Wh (98.6%)
CPU:
  Info: 14-core (6-mt/8-st) 12th Gen Intel Core i7-12700H [MST AMCP]
    speed (MHz): avg: 1564 min/max: 400/4679:4700:3500
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] driver: nvidia
    v: 515.48.07
  Device-3: Microdia Dual Mode Camera (8006 VGA) type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,usbhid
  Device-4: Chicony USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Device-5: Acer HD Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    resolution: 1: 5120x1440 2: 1920x1080~144Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.1
```

Comment: *The problems seems to be realted to conflict between the nvidia and intel cards* Not at all, only one is in use at any given time. And the Grub parameters afffect the iGPU Intel only. Is that the one you're using when the problem occurs? If so try using Nvidia instead. But perhaps the most important troubleshooting step is updating UEFI.

Comment: Ok I will try to update UEFI.

Comment: I've update the firmware, but the problem still persist only on plasma.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution because, finally I've found the real cause of this bug.
The problem was related to this log :

i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG:

I've found a solution, that solved also some flickering  problem.
It is not a driver or uefi.

UPDATE THE KERNEL

My previous kernel was 5.15.0 and the problem has been solved from 5.15.6 ( but I've some problem with this version ) so I've update to 5.19.3 and everything now seems to work fine.

To check your kernel version :

```
uname -mrs
```

To update the kernel I've found this very usefull solution:

[To update kernel](https://linuxhint.com/install-upgrade-latest-kernel-ubuntu-22-04/)

I strongly suggest to update the bios (uefi) too.

Answer (score 0):

util now, I **cannot** fix this problem:

- open visual code, new some edited file but not save
- close all file => show dialog confirm => click 'dont save' too fast
  ==> mouse stuck.

**Temp solution:**

1. Go to setting > bind Alt + Shift + ESC for this script(and press it when stuck):
   **reset_kwin.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 kwin --replace &
```

2. chmod a+x reset_kwin.sh